# iPhone 14 Pro Max keyboard adding extra letter when typing

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I just got a new iPhone 14 Pro Max and it has the iOS17 beta version installed. Whenever I type fast and send a message most of the times the last letter of the last word will be duplicated. (See the attached video) On the video it only happens with the word “Okay” but it happens with a bunch of other words as well and is very annoying.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/a6i7yp2g0m0j3wh7wcdez/Video-03-09-2023-10-41-00-in-the-morning.mp4?rlkey=m091710hwiws2pfkx614xt27u&dl=0

Comment: It's Beta software; did you report the issue to Apple?   What happens if you reset the device to an iOS 16 release?